# Using the bijection rule to count binary strings with even parity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

Let B = {0, 1}. Bn is the set of binary strings with n bits. Define the set En to be the set of binary strings with n bits that have an even number of 1's. Note that zero is an even number, so a string with zero 1's (i.e., a string that is all 0's) has an even number of 1's.

(a)
Show a bijection between B^9 and E^10. Explain why your function is a bijection.

(b)
What is |E^10|?

I having trouble finding a solution that satisfies the set and is a bijection. How do I approach solving this problem.

Is it something to do with cases? For exampple, if B^9 has an even number of one's add a zero, and if there is an odd number of one's add a one to obtain E^10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(a) Every string in E^10 begins with a prefix of length nine which is also a member of B^9. Given the prefix of length nine, the last bit is uniquely determined since it either must be 0 (if the prefix is also in E^9) or it must be 1 (if the prefix is not also in E^9). Therefore, for each element of E^10, there is exactly one element of B^9 to which it is uniquely mapped. Similarly, for any element in B^9, an element of E^10 can be uniquely formed by adding either a 0 or a 1 to the end of the element in B^9 (choosing the one that results in parity). This operation - appending either 0 or 1 to create parity - maps each element of B^9 to a unique element of E^10. Because there is a unique mapping from all E^10 to B^9, and from all B^9 to E^10, we have our bijection.

(b) Because there is a bijection between B^9 and E^10, we know |E^10| = |B^9|. But |B^9| = 2^9, since for each of the nine positions in any string in B^9 we can independently choose one of two values for the bit. Therefore, |E^10| = 2^9 also.